# How to pass global variable in json body in postman

Tags: postman

Hi I am trying to use global variable in raw j son body in postman. This is my body and how i am using the global variable

```
{"ci Token": "{{token}}"}
```

If the mode is url encoded its working but if its raw its not working Even though the variable is within double curly braces the value is not getting populated. It's showing nothing when i hover over the variable. Can someone please help to resolve this. Thank you in advance